# How to get webpack and babel to handle private typescript keyword?

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

I have webpack and babel compiling typescript but they don't seem to know how to handle the `private` keyword in Typescript.  They don't seem to have a problem with Typescript in general, I'm able to compile files.  So I'm wondering if I need to do some config changes but googling is not helping.

How do you get webpack and babel to play nice with Typescript's private keyword?

`.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript",
        "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

`webpack.config.js:`
...

```
{
            test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
        },
```

EDIT: There has been a request for reproduction details, I think this one is pretty easy to reproduce with what I've provided.  I've seen it in the past and it has to do with babel-loader's quasi support of typescript.  Create a class and add a private field to it.  `private whatever: string`.  That should be enough to make the `unrecognized token` error appear with the config I've provided.

EDIT 2:  `package.json` as requested:

```
{
  "name": "blah",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "blah config",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "bundle": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "check-types": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.2.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "tslint-immutable": "^6.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.46",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  }
}
```

Example of failure:

```
class Example {
 private anyField = 'danger';
}
```

Example of error message:

```
SyntaxError [path] Unexpected token (2:12)
  1 | class Example {
> 2 |     private anyField = 'danger';
    |             ^
```

Comment: This can help? https://2ality.com/2019/10/babel-loader-typescript.html

Comment: Why are you avoiding using typescript loader for .ts files?

Comment: @RazRonen - I've made it work with the babel-loader in the past and I followed a setup tutorial that worked with typescript.  I'm just not getting the private fields to work.  I was hoping that it would have better interoperability between typescript and javascript.  But yeah, maybe the ts-loader would be better if it can handle the private fields.

Comment: [awesome-typescript-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/awesome-typescript-loader) would be straight forward easy solution in my opinion. btw seems like a real legit question... Don't know why someone would downvote.

Comment: @RazRonen - Thanks for the advice, I'll see if I can get it to work using the ts-loader in babel and if not perhaps the awesome loader or another.

Comment: What do you mean *"don't seem to know how"*? Give a [mre] - what actually happens?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - There isn't much "unrecognized token" is the error on the 'private' keyword.  What I've already given should more than enough to repllicate it, have you tried using the config I provided and you can't replicate it?

Comment: Can you please post your package.json file? We need to know the typescript version and Babel version

Comment: @AntoineRaoulIscaros ok, sure.  I used the default versions, within the last couple days.

Comment: However much there is, could you put that *in the question*? Having the actual error makes this much more discoverable for someone else with a similar problem. How is React relevant here, which script is actually failing? And why would you describe a class instead of just providing it? This is 101 stuff, please set a better example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - The react code works fine, its just the private keyword.  Have you tried any of this, are you saying you got a private keyword to compile with what I provided above?

Comment: Then it might be helpful to strip out the React-related config. And no, I'm not saying that; it's not currently an MRE and I didn't fancy taking on the potential yak shaving.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Ok, so first you want more detail and more detail and then less.  The problem with adding all these details is that they are probably irrelevant and are distracting from the actual issue.  Do you have expertise in the issue I'm trying to solve?

Comment: I want a MRE (might mean adding some things, might mean removing others - e.g. right now the Webpack config seems partial) so that: 1. I or anyone else can easily run it locally to reproduce the issue and experiment to try to solve it; and 2. someone else with the same output would find this and solve their problem too, making both of our efforts worthwhile. I'd have guessed you wanted that too. I suppose I don't really get why someone at your (our!) rep and understanding of this site seems quite so unwilling to provide what is considered a basic part of SO questions (and debugging generally).

Comment: FWIW the Babel REPL seems happy enough with it: https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAqAWBLAdgc2gbwFDWgBwCdEA3MAFwFNoAzAe1ugF5oAiAIzAJYG4sBfLEA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Ctypescript&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.11.1&externalPlugins=%40babel%2Fplugin-proposal-class-properties%407.10.4

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I'm just trying to keep the question focused on the actual issue.  That's why I'm hestitant to add all this detail.  If someone with expertise is like, hey why didn't you include this or that?  Then by all means I'll add it, but the problem is just adding more and more info is just distracting from the fundamental problem.  Ie that babel has trouble with private keywords in relation to fields.  I've had experience with this in the past, so I know that its probably obvious to people who've run into it in the past.  I more need a quick suggestion than reproducibility.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I'm not trying to pick a fight with you, I'm just try to keep the question at a higher level, since reproducibility isn't the issue.  It should be reproducible with ease.  That's why I keep asking if you can reproduce or if you have expertise. If you can't reproduce then please tell me, if you have expertise in this issue then please tell me.  If you've used a `private` keyword with babel and its no problem then please tell me that. But beyond that its not going to mean much to people who haven't dealt with the issue.  Does that make any sense?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Allright, well it is interesting that the online babel compiler seems to not care.  Perhaps that will give me a lead.  Thanks for trying anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need [babel-preset-typescript-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-typescript-vue)

- version 1.1.1 for Vue@2.7
- version 1.1.0 for Vue@<2.7

Answer (score -1):

Changing the directory that the file was in had some impact in how it was compiled. I'm not entirely sure how or why that had an impact. The file that had trouble with was on a directory branch two levels lower than the base webpack config that pointed to it. While files that were above the webpack.config allowed for `private` typescript keywords, the file below that directory level did not allow for a `private` keyword.

Perhaps the lower directory levels were being read as classic javascript despite the file extension for some reason?

By default the latest versions of the babel/webpack setup should allow Typescript compilation with both the `private` and `readonly` keywords.  Though there was a time when babel had trouble with those keywords. If you're running into trouble consider experimenting with the directory structure. I'm guessing someone with more expertise might be able to tell me why the directory level matters even if the compilation starts where the configuration files are located.

Comment: In other words, the problem *wasn't* reproducible from the information in the question? If only someone with expertise had been here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I still don't why its broken.  No one asked for the directory structure and its not usual to provide it.  Was it necessary to come here and gloat about it?

Comment: I asked repeatedly for a [mre], something I could run locally. This is a basic debugging step and required by e.g. [ask], so doesn't seem to me to be unreasonable. But not only did you refuse to provide it, you were condescending. Next time please take any feedback a little more graciously; people asking for more information probably want to try to help.

Comment: Heck, I think between this Q and A you actually have an interesting question (or bug report): why does it break depending on the source file's location relative to the configuration? Making a MRE would have helped you find and ask that, and I'd suggest editing this question to do so.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Please, I don't agree with you, but I have no desire to argue.  Your passion might be better spent trying to actually help someone than berating me with your views.